# How to destine the configure generated files to special path?

Tags: c, configure

How to destine the configure output files path?

in some case I only can configure like this:

```
/root/src/my_software-1.8.2/configure
```

in my case, I can not cd into `/root/src/my_software-1.8.2/`.

I will generate these files to `/`:

```
 2 00:06 ..
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root     0 Sep 27 07:32 .dockerenv
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root 24790 Oct  2 00:06 Makefile
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    53 Sep 28 11:24 att
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root     7 May 11  2019 bin -> usr/bin
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root  3934 Oct  2 00:06 config.h
-rw-r--r--.   1 root root 31584 Oct  2 00:06 config.log
-rwxr-xr-x.   1 root root 33874 Oct  2 00:06 config.status
```

I want destine these generated files to special output path(`/root/src/my_software-1.8.2/`)?  how?

---

**EDIT-01**

In fact, I use the command to execute script:

```
docker exec -it centos-03 "my command"
```

but I can not execute the compound command like this:

```
docker exec -it centos-03  "cd /root/src/my_software-1.8.2/;./configure"
```

so I want use one command to do that.

Comment: If you can't `cd` into the directory, you can't run the script.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler See my edit, bro.

Comment: Try putting ’sh’ and `-c` as arguments before the string containing `cd`.

Comment: this helps, thank you.  but this post is not related to docker execute `sh -c`, I can still remain it.